# Compilation (genericity) issues overriding Properties.putAll

Tags: java, generics, properties

For my JavaFX UI, I implemented a class `ObservableProperties` that extends `java.util.Properties` and enables to listen the changes of some properties (in particular, the localized texts of the UI).

It works perfectly fine but now I would like to override the `putAll` method and I am having some issues with that.

First, as `Properties extends Hashtable<Object,Object>`, I would expect to be able to override

```
@Override
public void putAll(Map<Object,Object> that)
```

but the compile won't let me (saying that I'm not overriding a super method), so I have to use

```
@Override
public void putAll(Map that)
```

I want to perform an action on the entries of `that` so I tried as usual

```
for (Map.Entry entry : that.entrySet())
```

but the compiler tells me **Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to Map.Entry**. However, with that second snippet

```
Set<Map.Entry> set = that.entrySet();
for (Map.Entry a : set);
```

it compiles...

To sum up, I would like to know :

- why I have to remove the bounds of `Map<K,V>` in the signature
- why the first `for` loop does not compile whereas it seems equivalent to the second one

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the signature of the putAll method wrong. To override the method from Hasttable the signature must match, so it should be:

```
@Override
public synchronized void putAll(Map<? extends Object, ? extends Object> t) {
}
```

The `? extends Object` allows you to pass any typed Map into the method. If the signature was just `putAll(Map<Object,Object> t)` then you would only be able to pass Maps of type `Map<Object,Object>`. Passing a `Map<String,String>` for example would give an error.

The first for loop won't compile because `that.entrySet()` is effectively returning a set of type `Set<Object>`. The for loop won't convert from Object to Map.Entry for you.

The second loop works, but with type safety warnings, because you're telling the compiler that the set is of type `Set<Map.Entry>` before you pass it to the for loop.

Comment: Great, that compiles. However, could you explain exactly what is the difference between using `Object` and  `? extends Object` ? Because actually, everything extends `Object`.